# How to store User's Data for Session in Flask?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I'm creating a Flask application that requires each request to use some data that a user has passed to the application to initialize their session. Once they have passed that data and initialized the session, I'd like to re-use that data over and over until their session is done to fill requests without them having to pass the data for each request.

I can't seem to figure out the best way to do this. Storing it in the session variable doesn't work because that data just gets sent back to the user and then its the same as just passing it every request. Storing the data in a database doesn't seem like the right choice because I need to throw it away at the end of the session, and I don't see any decorator to implement for when a session expires...so I'm afraid my database will just end up filling up with all of these data that come from initialization and no guaranteed way to remove them at the end of a session.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/ perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options here: a session stored on the client, or a session stored on the server.

To store it on the server, you need a data-store.  If your app ever has to scale to any extent (including multiple uwsgi workers), you will have to use a distributed store.  If you have redis, that would be the best choice.  See the Flask-Session example posted by Simon Fraser in the comments to do this.  It will handle storing the session object in your database and fetching values from it when needed.  It handles a large number of backends as well, so whatever database you have will probably work with it out of the box.

If you don't want to use a backend session, you have to use a client session.  This is done by setting a cookie- cookies are automatically attached to most requests the browser sends to your site, so values that you store on the cookie will usually come back to you.  (this is how facebook remembers who you are without you logging in on every page.  In fact, it is how the Flask-Session keeps track of WHICH session to restore!).  In order for this to be reliable, you have to sign the cookie so the user can't modify the values- Flask can handle this for you with the built in [Session](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#sessions), or you can use a better crypto library as described [Here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/51/).  If you don't want the user to be able to see the values, or if you have a lot of data to store (the maximum size of a cookie is limited), you will have to use the server side version of all of this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've used the session variable with cookies, but the problem is that I end up sending the giant 20,000 byte piece of data for every request instead of actually storing it on the session side and utilizing it for all the requests afterward.

When I think about using mongodb or redis for my session data, I don't know how to handle clearing that session data out when the session ends. There doesn't seem to be any decorator that I can run for a session teardown so that the redis/mongodb can be cleared of the session data when it is no longer needed.

Comment: you never know when the session is over- you have no idea what the user is doing in their browser between requests.  You could empty the session in your 'logout' function if that makes sense for your app.  Probably more pertinent, you could just set a short ETL on the data in redis and let the database handle cleanup for you.

Comment: Right, I get that I don't know when the session is over. To get around that, I've set my session lifetime to 5 minutes and that time gets refreshed every time a user executes a request. So in reality, I know that the session will end 5 minutes after their last request. I'm curious if there's a way to handle the teardown when the session times out?

When you say ETL, do you mean extract/transform/load or another mechanism I'm not aware of that is specific to these DBs?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say TTL, I guess I have ETL on the brain.  Redis will let you expire values after a set time (with the TTL) option.  Haven't used Mongo enough to know if it offers something similar.

Comment: That should work. I think all I need to do is refresh the TTL for every request and it will be in sync with the session timing out. I appreciate the help! Mind adding this info in your first answer for others to see?